# Python PANDAS: Groupby Transform Sum Unique

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a situation where I am creating a pivot table in PANDAS where it makes more sense to calculate the fields separately and just use .pivot_table() for the pivot step.  However, I am running into some difficultly trying to calculate the denominator for my percentages.  Essentially, due to the data format I appear to need to do something like "groupby transform unique sum" on the second line below (which is where I am stuck):

```
df['numerator'] = df.groupby(['category1','category2'])['customer_id'].transform('nunique')
df['denominator'] =  df.groupby(['category2'])['numerator'].nunique().transform('sum')
df['percentage'] = (df['numerator'] / df['denominator'])

df_pivot  = df.pivot_table(index='category1',
                           columns=['category2'],
                           values=['numerator','percentage']) \
                           swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)

df_pivot.loc['total', :] = df_pivot.sum().values
```

My apologies for not being able to provide any dummy data, but I would appreciate any tips if I have hopefully provided enough detail to reason about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need lambda function with `unique` and `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numerator':[3,1,1,9,2,2],
                   'category2':list('aaabbb')})

#print (df)

df['denominator']=df.groupby(['category2'])['numerator'].transform(lambda x: x.unique().sum())
```

Alternative solution with `set`s and `sum`s:

```
df['denominator']=df.groupby(['category2'])['numerator'].transform(lambda x: sum(set(x)))
```

---

```
print (df)
  category2  numerator  denominator
0         a          3            4
1         a          1            4
2         a          1            4
3         b          9           11
4         b          2           11
5         b          2           11
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your insight and so quickly!  Ahh, I see my mistake now. I had tried .transform(lambda x: sum(x.unique())) originally.  Thanks as always.